# Making VirtualBox VM fullscreen on MacOS

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualbox-guest-additions

I am using MacOS Mojave and have installed VirtualBox VM. My OS in VM is Ubuntu. My problem is that I want my VM machine to be fullscreen. I have tried every method given on stackoverflow but none seems to work.
I have read that

> ***Oracle VM VirtualBox does not provide Guest Additions for Mac OS X at this time***.

I found the above statment on https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html 
**Does this mean that fullscreen is not possible?**
If there is a way to fullscreen, then kindly let me know.

**Edit: Removed Image**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is possible for Guest Ubuntu to get fullscreen in Host Mac**. You need to install Guest Additions. You can get them(for virtualbox 6.1) here-
[Guest Addtions](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.0/)
 -

Open your Terminal.

```
    sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```